# Pandas sum(axis=1) does not add the values in the row, it concatenates them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file with 500 rows and 5 columns, I want to find the sum of all the values in a row using Pandas. But by doing sum(axis=1) does not add up the values in a row, it concatenates them.

## loading the csv file

```
sys1 = pd.read_csv('exam/data/System1/time/task1.csv', names=headerList)
sys_task1 = sys1.Task1.str.split(expand=True)
sys_task1
```

## printing the dataframe

```
      0       1       2       3       4
0   3.03    1.15    1.83    1.97    2.09
1   3.12    1.12    1.93    1.90    2.19
2   3.05    1.12    1.97    1.97    2.12
3   2.97    1.20    1.94    1.94    2.08
4   3.01    1.21    2.00    1.99    2.11
... ... ... ... ... ...
495 2.98    1.15    1.87    2.00    2.06
496 3.08    1.12    1.86    1.96    2.11
497 2.97    1.25    2.00    1.94    2.21
498 3.00    1.26    1.95    2.07    2.05
499 3.04    1.20    1.85    1.99    2.19
500 rows × 5 columns
```

## adding rows

```
sys_task1.sum(axis=1)
```

## result after adding

```
0      3.031.151.831.972.09
1      3.121.121.931.902.19
2      3.051.121.971.972.12
3      2.971.201.941.942.08
4      3.011.212.001.992.11
               ...         
495    2.981.151.872.002.06
496    3.081.121.861.962.11
497    2.971.252.001.942.21
498    3.001.261.952.072.05
499    3.041.201.851.992.19
Length: 500, dtype: object
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: do `sys_task1 = sys1.Task1.str.split(expand=True).astype(float)` and then do the sum, or `sys_task1.astype(float).sum(axis=1)` right now they are strings

Comment: The reason is those values are stored as string in your dataframe, and need to typecast them first to float